Use json file string to enum shows Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number' as required for computed enum member values
I have a enum like this:
export enum AccountSettings {
  accountManagement = "Account management",
  managementOfRelatives = 'Management of relatives',
}

Then I have a en.json file, I want to use them for my enum data
{
  "account_management": "Account management",
  "management_of_relatives": "Management of relatives",
}

Then use it get the error:
import en from './en.json';

export enum AccountSettings {
  accountManagement = en.account_management, // shows Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'
  managementOfRelatives = 'Management of relatives',
}

How do I use en.json data to enum ?

Why would you want to do that?

Unfortunately you are hitting 2 successive issues:

JSON imported content is evaluated "normally" by TypeScript, as if you had a normal big variable structure. Hence the property value considered as string. With a variable in a .ts file, we could have used an as const assertion to mark the entire structure as readonly and enable TS inferring the literal values. But that is currently not possible for a JSON imported file, see e.g. ms/TS#32063

Even within a .ts file, TypeScript accepts a literal string value as a string enum representation only if it is defined very simply, e.g. in a const variable value directly; as soon as it is slightly more complex (e.g. even in a readonly object), TS refuses it, with the same error:


const foo = "bar"
//    ^? "bar" literal string

enum EnumFoo {
    Foo = foo // Okay
}

const fooObj = {
    foo
    //^? "bar"
} as const // const assertion

enum EnumFooObj {
    Foo = fooObj.foo // Error
}

const bar = fooObj.foo
//    ^? "bar"

enum EnumBar {
    Foo = bar // Error
}

Playground Link
